# Вывод переменной внутри значения другой переменной

Tags: php

Возможно ли вывести значение переменной внутри значения другой переменной?
Вот оригинал кода:

```
<?php
$catalog = '<div id="cat">
        ....
            <li><?echo $toyota;/*вот тут не выводится*/ ?></li>
        ....
</div>';
?>
```

Ну вобщем как то так, не знаю как сформировать вопрос:( 
Помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$toyota = 'тест';
$catalog = 'Это новый ' . $toyota;
echo $catalog; // Это новый тест
```

А вообще читайте — [**конкатенация php**](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+php&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=ru&newwindow=1&client=opera&hs=Yyp&rls=ru&channel=suggest&sa=X&ei=RdxhT-KpGtP44QSK9JjeBw&ved=0CBwQvwUoAQ&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+php&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4dd51c1482dbc2fd&biw=1680&bih=863).

Answer (score 0):

иногда допускают вот такую ошибку:

```
$toyota = 'тест';
 $catalog = "Это новый $toyota";
 $toyota = 'автомобиль';
 echo $catalog;
```

и ожидают в переменной $catalog фразу 'Это новый автомобиль', хотя строчка $catalog уже определилась ранее.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$catalog = '<div id="cat">
    ....
        <li>' . $toyota . '</li>
    ....
</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php $toyota = "Toyota mark 2";
      $catalog = "Каталог запчастей для автомобиля $toyota"; echo $catalog; ?>
```

Comment: В нутри переменной почему то не работает вторая переменная. И при выводе $catalog - выводится значение "Каталог запчастей для автомобиля $toyota" в место полного каталога который лежит в $toyota

Comment: @speednext вот так

     $catalog = "Каталог запчастей для автомобиля " . $toyota;

Comment: Главное, что бы основная переменная  т.е  $catalog  была обрамлена в двойные кавычки  "  а не одинарные  '   Это важно.

Дай полный код,как ты выводишь

Comment: $catalog = "Каталог запчастей для автомобиля " . $toyota; Таким образом вроде выведется каталог всех запчастей.. Хотя..., щас испытаю=)

Comment: А что собственно в переменной  $toyota не массив ли случаем?

Comment: Не, не массив, там занчения через запятую.
Я оригинал кода добавил.

Comment: <?php
include('avtomobili.php');//тут лижат переменные с марками авто.
//Выводим HTML теги.
$catalog = '<div id="cat">
<div id="m2">
....//теги
<li>/*Нужно вывести вот тут $toyota*/</li>
....//теги
</div> ';
?>
//Уже запутался... Чего то я сам уже не пойму что я тут намутил!

Answer (score -1):

Или можно произвести вывод без конкатенации, использую двойные кавычки:

```
 $toyota = 'тест';
 $catalog = "Это новый $toyota";
 echo $catalog; // Это новый тест
```

Comment: Это медленнее.

Comment: Этот кратчайший промежуток времени не заметен для человека, даже если идет последовательная многократная обработка и вывод в таком виде.

Comment: С конкатенацией код менее читабелен. Если в строку надо вставить 5-10 переменных глазу не очень приятно. А эффект от этого будет виден только (и то врятли) при 5-10 тысячах онлайн. Но при такой посещаемости думать надо о более тонких местах (sql запросы например,оптимизация БД).  Не зря говорят преждевременная оптимизация зло.
Если бы использование обычного метода было намного хуже конкатенации, то смысл был его делать тогда?

Comment: @Asen, я знаю, но это нельзя называть преждевременной оптимизацией, т.к. это не требует усилий.
@Inart, лично мне неприятно смотреть на

    "Это новый $toyota";

Мне нравится конкатенация.

Comment: согласен. Тут на любителя уже. Кто как привык =)

Comment: Ну и кто это проголосовал против !?